# If $(X,\left \| \cdot \right \|_{\mathcal{F}})$ is a Banach space then $\mathcal{F} \subset B(X,Y)$

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose $X,Y$ are Banach spaces and $\mathcal{F} \ne \emptyset$  is a collection of linear (non neccesary bounded) operators such that $\sup_{T \in \mathcal{F}}\left \| T(x) \right \|<\infty$. Define $\| \cdot \|_{\mathcal{F}}$  by $\| x \|_{\mathcal{F}}= \| x  \| + \sup_{T \in \mathcal{F}}\left \| T(x) \right \|$.

Prove the following three are equivalent:

1. $\mathcal{F}\subset B(X,Y)$;
2. The norms $\| \cdot \|_{\mathcal{F}}$, $\| \cdot \|$ are equivalent;
3. $(X,\| \cdot \|_{\mathcal{F}})$ is a Banach space.

So far I've proved that $1 \to 2 $ and $2 \to 3$  (In fact I know the parts $2,3$ are equivalent) but couldn't find a way to make the implication $3 \to 1$ or $2 \to 1$. Could you please help me find a way to prove this implication.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will show that (2) $\implies$ (1). Since the norms are equivalent, we can find a constant $M>0$ such that for all $x\in X$ it is $$\|x\|+\sup_{T\in\mathcal{F}}\|Tx\|\leq M\|x\|$$
or equivalently (obviously $M\geq1$) we have that there exists a constant $M\geq0$ such that for all $x\in X$ it is

$$\sup_{T\in\mathcal F}\|Tx\|\leq M\|x\|$$
Now if $T$ is an operator of $\mathcal F$, then $\|Tx\|\leq M\|x\|$, thus $T$ is bounded, i.e. $T\in B(X,Y)$. This is true for all $T\in\mathcal F$, thus $\mathcal{F}\subset B(X,Y)$.

Comment: Why didnt I see it! Very clear, thank you.

Comment: @ipreferpi No problem, don't worry we all get stuck sometimes (even at simple stuff). For the implication (1) -> (2) I assume you used the principle of uniform boundedness? (also, if this answer covers your question, please accept it:) )

Comment: Yeah I used it. I have to wait to accept your answer since you posted to fast :D

Comment: @ipreferpi hahah, thanks!

Comment: Now that I was writing everything I see that I haven't proved 3 implies 2 and the cycle comes again because I think its easier to do 3 implies 1.

Comment: @ipreferpi Show that 3 implies 2: Obviously $\|\cdot\|\leq\|\cdot\|_F$. For the reverse, consider the identity operator $I:(X,\|\cdot\|)\to(X,\|\cdot\|_F)$. It suffices to show that $I$ is continuous. Since both spaces are Banach and $I$ is epi, use the closed graph theorem to prove that $I$ is continuous.